# Setting the zoom level in MapKit Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mapkit

How can I set the zoom level of my Google MapKit in SDK? Like for example, I live in New York, and I've set up 4 coordinate positions in my ProjectName-info.plist (URL Types > Item 0 > URL Schemes > Item 0), then I've set up my code in my UIViewController subclass file:

```
#import "GoogleMap.h"
#import "MyAnnotation.h"

@implementation GoogleMap

        - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        variable1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                                             pathForResource:@"NewYorkAreas" 
                                                             ofType:@"plist"]];

        double minLat = [[variable1 valueForKeyPath:@"@min.latitude"] doubleValue];
        double maxLat = [[variable1 valueForKeyPath:@"@max.latitude"] doubleValue];
        double minLon = [[variable1 valueForKeyPath:@"@min.longitude"] doubleValue];
        double maxLon = [[variable1 valueForKeyPath:@"@max.longitude"] doubleValue];

        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        region.center.latitude = (maxLat + minLat) / 2.0;
        region.center.longitude = (maxLon + minLon) / 2.0;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = (maxLat - minLat) * 1.05;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = (maxLon - minLon) * 1.05;
        map.region = region;

        for (NSDictionary *newYorkAreasDict in variable1){
            MyAnnotation *annotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithDictionary:newYorkAreasDict];
            [map addAnnotation:annotation];
            [annotation release];
        }
    }

    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

        if (map.userLocation == annotation){
            return nil;
        }

        NSString *identifier = @"MY_IDENTIFIER";

        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (annotationView == nil){
            annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                                           reuseIdentifier:identifier] 
                              autorelease];
            annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        }
        return annotationView;
    }
```

So this is all I have for now in my code, which works perfectly when I run and debug the app, and shows me the location of all 4 areas that I set in a good zooming level, but now I want only 1 area to set, so when I erased the other 3 area and when running it and only giving me one area, the zooming level seems very close to the map:

[image]

So I when the code is fixed (assuming someone helped me fix the code for the zooming level), the next time I run it, when I click on "Find us on Google Map", my Google Map opening page zoom level should look like this:
[image]

So yea hopefully someone can help me fix this zooming level when I begin opening Google Map, thanks!

(About the New York variable names, forget it, I don't live in New York lol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a minimum value for latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta. I would do it something like this:

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((maxLat + minLat) / 2.0, (maxLon + minLon) / 2.0), 1000.0, 1000.0);
region.span.latitudeDelta = MAX(region.span.latitudeDelta, (maxLat - minLat) * 1.05);
region.span.longitudeDelta = MAX(region.span.longitudeDelta, (maxLon - minLon) * 1.05);
```

The first line creates a region with a 1km by 1km rectangle, and the following lines enlarge the rectangle if the points are spread farther.

Comment: hey thanks for your help, when I ran it, it gave me a   "_CLLocationCoordinate2DMake", referenced from:
-[GoogleMap viewDidLoad] in GoogleMap.o
symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Maybe you could help me with this error? thanks

Comment: You would need the Core Location framework for that function. If you don't want to include the framework just for that, try replacing `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((maxLat + minLat) / 2.0, (maxLon + minLon) / 2.0)` with `(CLLocationCoordinate2D){ (maxLat + minLat) / 2.0, (maxLon + minLon) / 2.0 }`.

Comment: wow, thank you so much! it really works! Now I can add a bit more stuff now! By the way, I have one more question, when users are somewhere else in a specific area, and when they tap my google button to open my google page, I want a route plotted between the user's current location and my business location, is it posible if you can help me with that? Thanks again!

Comment: That would be a matter for a separate question.

Comment: At first it worked using your exemple but now the region is changeing but it doesn't make the zoom on that region